# How to add new text inputs row by row on clicking a button in streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

I want to add an event to a button such that whenever the button is clicked new text inputs are added row by row.

[image: Below is the webpage in which I want to add new text inputs row by row on clicking the button]

Answer (score 1):

This might not be an optimal solution, but it works. You'll need to store the number of rows in a session state variable (https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state). The variable "n_rows" is incremented everytime the add button is pressed, and we loop through "n_rows" number of times to create each row. Use st.experimental_rerun() to update the screen as soon as the button is pressed. Make sure to pass the index in loop as key.

```
if 'n_rows' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.n_rows = 1

add = st.button(label="add")

if add:
    st.session_state.n_rows += 1
    st.experimental_rerun()

for i in range(st.session_state.n_rows):
    #add text inputs here
    st.text_input(label="Column Name", key=i) #Pass index as key
```

Comment: I think you you have forgotten "n_" in : 
if add:
    st.session_state.n_rows += 1
    st.experimental_rerun()